# attach event to dynamic element

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hey im having a problem attaching an event to an element im dynamically generating. I would appreciate any advice on solving the issue im not sure whether its the method that im using to attach the event or whether its something else:

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) { 
itemlist=itemlist.concat('<pre'+' id="pres'+i+'"'+'>'+array[i]+'</pre>');

var name = '#pres'+i;
$( name ).click(function() {
  alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
});
}
```

I also tried this method which i found on stack overflow however yielded no result :

```
var name = '#pres'+i;
$(name).on('click', function() {
    alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
});
```

Whilst inspecting in chrome all of the elements exist with the correct ID, however the jquery event i have attached does not perform its alert. I have looked at some solutions however i do not want to attach the same function to all "" tags however attaching the same event to each of the ones in the loop would be acceptable.
Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Is the `i` variable declared with `var` further up?

Comment: ah valid point, i have not declared var i prior to the loop, iv edited it now to : for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) { however still does not function correctly

Comment: Check this: https://jsfiddle.net/caypL7dk/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of generating unique `id` attributes, which makes the code needlessly more complex and can be a pain to maintain, you could instead use a single common class and attach a single delegated event handler to all the elements. Try this:

```
$('#myContainer').on('click', '.foo', function() {
    // handle the element click here...
    console.log($(this).text());
});

var html = '';
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) { 
    html += '<pre class="foo">' + array[i] + '</pre>';
}
$('#myContainer').append(html);
```

Comment: I mean that they've changed `for (i = 0` to `for (var i = 0`.

Comment: @gcampbell ah! I see what you mean now. Thanks :)

Comment: This solution worked very well, took a bit of restructure but solved the problem very nicely :) thanks everyone who commented and helped!

Answer (score 2):

Rory McCrossan's answer is the simplest way to do it if you just add the elements at the beginning and set their .click after that.
However, if you call the generating function sometime later than that, I'd suggest using something like this, a function that sets the .click event handler for each element when it is created.

You can still have your IDs and so on, you just don't really need them.

```js
    var itemlist=[]
    var array=["Element 1","Element 2","Element 3"]
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        element=$('<pre' + ' id="pres' + i + '"' + '>' + array[i] + '</pre>');
        $(element).click(function () {
            alert("Handler for .click() called.");
        });
        itemlist.push(element);
    }
    $("body").append(itemlist)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `on` method in the container that contains all `pre` elements, like code bellow.

Suppose you have this result:

```
<div class="container-pre">
  <pre id="pres1" data-id="1" class="pre-element">Some text 1</pre>
  <pre id="pres2" data-id="2" class="pre-element">Some text 2</pre>
  <pre id="pres3" data-id="3" class="pre-element">Some text 3</pre>
</div>
```

Then your jQuery configuration would like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".container-pre").on("click", ".pre-element", function(e) {
        var elem = $(e.currentTarget);
        var id = elem.attr("data-id");
        alert( "Handler for .click() called at element " + id);
    });
});
```

You can see this plunker with this code in action:

https://embed.plnkr.co/v61GxazfsT8RscuMTxI9/